# Mock Dependency class or class method per test case wise but not globally in FastAPI

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi

I have my router method in FastAPI which depends on some JWT authentication mechanism. I want to mock my authentication to bypass the auth to test my API easily. To mock, I am using [pytest-fastapi-deps 0.2.3](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-fastapi-deps/)
. Here is my router

```
# object_manager.routers.object_get_save_router.py

@router.post("/upload", status_code=201)
async def upload_object(request: Request, response: Response, jwt_payload: dict = Depends(CheckPermission(permission_list=['can_upload_object']))):
    body = await request.form()
    
    res, objects = <Some service method>

    return JSONResponse(res)
```

Here is my CheckPermission class

```
# auth.auth_handler.py

oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="token")

async def validate_jwt_token(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    
    try:
        <Some valdation>
        return payload
    except jwt.exceptions.DecodeError as error:
        raise error


class CheckPermission:
    def __init__(self, permission_list: List[str]):
        self.permission_list = permission_list
        self.jwt_payload = {}

    async def __call__(self, jwt_payload: dict = Depends(validate_jwt_token)):
        <Some additional valdation>

        return jwt_payload
```

Here is my test class

```
# tests.routers.test_base_file_upload_method.py

from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from auth.auth_handler import validate_jwt_token, CheckPermission
from main import app

test_client = TestClient(app)


async def validate_jwt_token_overriden(token: str = ''):
    return {
        'userId': 'testuser'
    }


class CheckPermissionOverriden:
    async def __call__(self, jwt_payload: dict):
        return {
            'userId': 'testuser'
        }

   

class TestFileUploadAPI:
    def test_no_input_error(self, fastapi_dep):
        with fastapi_dep(app).override({
            validate_jwt_token: validate_jwt_token_overriden,
            CheckPermission.__call__: CheckPermissionOverriden.__call__
        }):
            response = test_client.post(url='/upload', headers={
                "Authorization": "Bearer some-token"
            })

        assert response.status_code == 400
```

My `validate_jwt_token` method gets overridden but I can not override `CheckPermission.__call__` method or the whole `CheckPermission` class. I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72204000/3257218) but could not make it work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks for using my library! Hope that it's trivial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the override works is to replace a **concrete object** that FastAPI wraps with depends. Imagine that every time you call `Depends(object)` that object is stored in the FastAPI dictionary (that is true for methods which are objects as well).

So an easy solution to your case would be to extract the object to a variable like so:

```
# object_manager.routers.object_get_save_router.py

cp = CheckPermission(permission_list=['can_upload_object'])

@router.post("/upload", status_code=201)
async def upload_object(request: Request, response: Response, jwt_payload: dict = Depends(cp)):
    body = await request.form()
    
    res, objects = <Some service method>

    return JSONResponse(res)
```

Then override it with the value you want (note the short syntax for simplicity):

```
class TestFileUploadAPI:
    def test_no_input_error(self, fastapi_dep):
        with fastapi_dep(app).override({
            validate_jwt_token: validate_jwt_token_overriden,
            cp: {'userId': 'testuser'},
        }):
            response = test_client.post(url='/upload', headers={
                "Authorization": "Bearer some-token"
            })

        assert response.status_code == 400
```